# classic asp page does not works properly on IE9

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, internet-explorer-9

I have an old popup page in an iframe wrote in classic asp that run fine in IE8 but does not in IE9.
It produce a long task and i show a wait message and a gif with a response.flush and after elaboration they turn respectively in success text and a anchor to download the produced file. This is done calling a script thru response.write in this way aftyer the elaboration end

```
Response.Write "<script language=Javascript>"   
Response.Write "afterExp();"
Response.Write "</SCRIPT>"
```

the afterExp funct do this

```
function afterExp() {

var f= document.getElementById("TDtxt");
var a= "Esportazione Terminata";
f.innerText = a

f= document.getElementById("TDimg");
a="<A id='A1' target='_blank' href='<%=sURL %>'>Apri File</A>"
f.innerHTML = a
f.align="right"
sdone="ok"
}
```

but now this is not refreshed and the page remains on the wait gif. The task ends anyway, i can see the file in the download folder.

ive investigate also iIS 7.5 issues but seems all fine. I think is an IE9 issue.
please help

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue with IE 9 and a long running task. It seems that some IE installers set a strange request timeout of 10seconds. There is no real explanation why that is, but it happens. So even on two identical windows 7 computers one can have the normal timeout and one has the 10second timeout (happend to us at work).

After 10 seconds IE will just end the task, but on the server it will continue and thus create the file. The solution is a changing the registry to allow for a larger timeout.

See the awnser at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/what-is-default-receivetimeout-for-ie9-get-error/457051d0-25a1-426d-bf19-4d912f946f8b?msgId=1c559500-08fe-420f-83ce-bedd57f208a9

Answer (score -1):

It is an `IE9` issue. It happens when you move the `IFrame` through the `DOM`. `IE9` executes the code continuously as you moves the `IFrame`.